# Are the Q&A posted on Stack Exchange websites valuable consideration?

Tags: contract-law

In order to form a legally binding contract it is necessary that both parties provide valuable consideration.

Is the provision by a user on this (or other Stack Exchange sites) of a question, answer or comment "valuable consideration" sufficient to form a contract?

Comment: As [I suggest here](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/1865/10): Not only are users who provide content providing valuable consideration, but so are visitors who merely load a page!

Comment: @feetwet The fact that a third-party pays on the basis of a users visit is **not** valuable consideration from the user - a contract **cannot** be formed on the because A provides a service for B for which C will pay for; A & C may have a contract and C may have provided a gift to A but A & B do not have a contract.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There's no requirement that the consideration be objectively valuable, as there's no real standard for value; as long as there is some consideration, it can be offered for a contract.

The [peppercorn rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppercorn_(legal)) states that nominal consideration is sufficient to constitute consideration for the purposes of establishing a contract. Even if later, we decide that the comments or posts are no longer desired, it does not cease to be good consideration.

Comment: Specifically then, the consideration would be in the licence the user provided under the T&C?

Comment: The content that is licensed to SE, yes.